# Nested variables in AppleScript

Tags: variables, loops, applescript

Using a simple loop in Applescript to create a variables that will assigned based on a pre-defined array already declared. Assignments are random. Goal is to create a variable with a subset that assigned a part of the array to a specific part within the variable. I need to keep track of where the part ends up later and reference it. Problem is one of syntax for the variable. 
For example, if I wanted to shuffle a deck of cards, it would look something like this:

```
 set cardlist to {"Ace of Spades", "2 of Spades", "3 of Spades", "4 of Spades", "5 of Spades", "6 of Spades", "7 of Spades", "8 of Spades", "9 of Spades", "10 of Spades", "Jack of Spades", "Queen of Spades", "King of Spades", "Ace of Diamonds", "2 of Diamonds", "3 of Diamonds", "4 of Diamonds", "5 of Diamonds", "6 of Diamonds", "7 of Diamonds", "8 of Diamonds", "9 of Diamonds", "10 of Diamonds", "Jack of Diamonds", "Queen of Diamonds", "King of Diamonds", "Ace of Hearts", "2 of Hearts", "3 of Hearts", "4 of Hearts", "5 of Hearts", "6 of Hearts", "7 of Hearts", "8 of Hearts", "9 of Hearts", "10 of Hearts", "Jack of Hearts", "Queen of Hearts", "King of Hearts", "Ace of Clubs", "2 of Clubs", "3 of Clubs", "4 of Clubs", "5 of Clubs", "6 of Clubs", "7 of Clubs", "8 of Clubs", "9 of Clubs", "10 of Clubs", "Jack of Clubs", "Queen of Clubs", "King of Clubs"}

-- shuffle deck
set deckcount to 1
set deckset to random number from 1 to 52
repeat 52 times
    set deskset to random number from 1 to 52
    set deckcard(subset) to item deckset in cardlist

    set deckcount to deckcount + 1
    set deckset to random number from 1 to 52
end repeat
```

I know that I'll have to worry about duplicates with the random # generator, and once I get the variable issue resolved, I can do that. But what I need is something along the lines of subsets. For example (deckcard.1 and deckcard.5). I just can't figure out how to get it to work. I've tried and read everything I can find.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May I suggest another approach. Defining card by an array of strings is not really defining them by values. What if you want to compare the cards in a game or something. Let's say you have 2 of spades and a Queen of hearts, how would you define which cards beats the other, if they're of the same color or even the same kind? You should need to split your string again and compare them with a lot of if statements.

My Suggestion would be using two numbers: one for it's value and one for it's kind. However using list with two values or an record with two keys for each card doesn't appeal me so I'll store two number into one. The card type has four different type of values, so bitwise it will only use 00, 01, 10 and 11. That means we can store all 4 values into 2 bits. So the first two bits of my card I'm going to use as kind of card. The remaining bits (only 4-bits needed max) are then used for the card value.

For example a binary value of 10010 is binary card value 100 and binary kind of card 10. Translated to decimal values: card kind 2 and card value 4, which could be a 5 of clubs. To split the value from it's kind and it's value we can use mod and div. Div 4 will shift the bits to the right, remove the first two bits (read: kind of card), which remains only the card value. Mod 4 will set all bits to 0 except the first 2, it'll remove the card value. With these two operators we can get the right data from the given integer. Here an example AppleScript that will work as explained.

```
-- We're going to use the first 2 bits to define the kind of the card (Heart, Spade, Club or Diamond)
-- The remaining bits we're going to define the card value
-- to get the card value we simply divide the value by 4 to remove the first two bits
-- to get kind of card we simply mod the value by 4 to keep the first two bits

-- create a deck
set deck to {}
repeat with x from 0 to 51
    set end of deck to x
end repeat

-- The deck is ordered; first by card value then by it's color (normally by color and then by value)
-- now we're going to shuffle the deck by picking randomly an item from the ordered list.
-- the picked item will be removed, so it won't be picked again and copied to the shuffled list
set shuffledDeck to {}
repeat until integers of deck = {}
    set seed to some integer of deck
    set end of shuffledDeck to seed
    set item (seed + 1) of deck to missing value
end repeat

-- now if we want a presentational form of the deck we can simply do this
set the cardValues to {"Ace", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "Jack", "Queen", "King"}
set the cardColors to {"Spades", "Hearts", "Clubs", "Diamonds"}

set stringsForShuffledDeck to {}
repeat with card in shuffledDeck
    set end of stringsForShuffledDeck to (item (card div 4 + 1) of cardValues) & " of " & (item (card mod 4 + 1) of cardColors)
end repeat

-- the whole point of using number values instead of an array of number
-- is to check which cards beats the other by value and or color
-- we're going to use the first 2 cards of the shuffled deck
set firstCard to item 1 of shuffledDeck
set secondCard to item 2 of shuffledDeck

if firstCard div 4 > secondCard div 4 then
    log item 1 of stringsForShuffledDeck & " beats " & item 2 of stringsForShuffledDeck
else if firstCard div 4 = secondCard div 4 then
    log item 1 of stringsForShuffledDeck & " equals " & item 2 of stringsForShuffledDeck
else
    log item 1 of stringsForShuffledDeck & " is less than " & item 2 of stringsForShuffledDeck
end if

-- Now compare card 3 and 4 of shuffled deck by color
set thirdCard to item 3 of shuffledDeck
set FourthCard to item 4 of shuffledDeck
if thirdCard mod 4 = FourthCard mod 4 then
    log item 3 of stringsForShuffledDeck & " is of the same kind as " & item 4 of stringsForShuffledDeck
else
    log item 3 of stringsForShuffledDeck & " is other kind as " & item 4 of stringsForShuffledDeck
end if

-- We have set the even numbers for black colored cards and odd number for red colors
-- Now we can determine very easily it's colors.
if thirdCard mod 2 = FourthCard mod 2 then
    log item 3 of stringsForShuffledDeck & " has the same color as " & item 4 of stringsForShuffledDeck
else
    log item 3 of stringsForShuffledDeck & " has other color as " & item 4 of stringsForShuffledDeck
end if
```

Comment: Thanks for the input! I did originally think about assigning variables to the suit and value of the card separately, so it's nice to know that my instincts were accurate.

Comment: Thanks for the input! I did originally think about assigning variables to the suit and value of the card separately, so it's nice to know that my instincts were accurate. I'm pretty sure I've wrapped my head around most of this, but I have a few questions about your code. 1) Why use '(seed+1)' instead of the item# seed for the loop that shuffles the deck? Because you used 0 to 51 as your original loop? Why not use 1-52 and leave seed as is? Thanks again!

Comment: The main reason is that approach the cards from a binary point of view and not from an logical human point or AppleScript point of view. Because when using card type in 2 bits ( 0 - 3) I thought it would be better to use the same staring value for card values. You can change that to your likings. Remember if you want to card type start from 1 as well you need to use other bit swifts (mod 8 and div 8) because byte value 100 is then the fourth card type so your card value must start at position 4 (bin 1000 = dec 8)